# ServerSocketChannel has been closed, but TCP ESTABLISHED still

Tags: java, sockets, nio

I have a ServerSocketChannel and a Socket.ServerSocket bind in port 8888. 
Socket connect to ServerSocket and send data.If I closed ServerSocket only, TCP still was ESTABLISHED.If I closed Socket only, there is no any ESTABLISHED.

I use following code to close ServerSocketChannel:

```
public void doStop() {
  try {
    acceptChannel.close();  //close ServerSocketChannel
    acceptChannel.socket().close(); //close ServerSocket
    LOG.debug("close server socket. " + acceptChannel.socket().isClosed());
  } catch (IOException ignore) {}
  try { selector.close(); } catch (IOException ignore) {}
}
```

There are two TCP status in here.

1.Before I closed ServerSocket:

```
zephyrdeiMac:~ zephyrguo$ lsof -i tcp:8888 -n
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    26272 zephyrguo   17u  IPv4 0x5f7a02f802ab0c75      0t0  TCP *:ddi-tcp-1 (LISTEN)
java    26272 zephyrguo   40u  IPv4 0x5f7a02f802b07715      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:52728->127.0.0.1:ddi-tcp-1 (ESTABLISHED)
java    26272 zephyrguo   41u  IPv4 0x5f7a02f7f9669ff5      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:ddi-tcp-1->127.0.0.1:52728 (ESTABLISHED)
```

2.After I closed ServerSocket:

```
zephyrdeiMac:~ zephyrguo$ lsof -i tcp:8888 -n
COMMAND   PID      USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
java    26272 zephyrguo   40u  IPv4 0x5f7a02f802b07715      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:52728->127.0.0.1:ddi-tcp-1 (ESTABLISHED)
java    26272 zephyrguo   41u  IPv4 0x5f7a02f7f9669ff5      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:ddi-tcp-1->127.0.0.1:52728 (ESTABLISHED)
```

ESTABLISHED is still in here, but no LISTEN.Socket can send data, but no response.

Comment: Are you sure the "remaining" connections are from the running program and not from some different instances? Your logs proof a single socket connection is being closed. This is what is to be expected.

Comment: Closing the `ServerSocketChannel` only stops it listening for new connections, existing connections are not affected.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Rotteveel     I also closed `ServerSocket`. Is this not affected also?

Comment: @ZephyrGuo No, 'closing the `ServerSocketChannel` only stops it listening for new connections: existing connections are not affected'. He already told you that, and he's right.

Answer (score 1):

1. Closing a `ServerSocketChannel` doesn't affect established connections in any way. Your expectations are incorrect.
2. A `ServerSocketChannel` or `SocketChannel` that is registered with a `Selector` stays open after `close()` until the next time you call `select()`. You can call `selectNow()` to force that. This is documented somewhere in the Javadoc that I can never find when I look for it. They do some trick with `dup()` to ensure you can't use the `SocketChannel` any more but the `Selector` won't break.

Comment: I have to call `select()` one more time for closing `ServerSocketChannel` really, although I call `ServerSocket.close()` and `ServerSocketChannel.close()`. Is that your meaning?

Comment: @ZephyrGuo I have already expressed my meaning. You're now asking me to repeat myself, or rather to confirm a mangled version of what I already said. It just wastes time.

Comment: Sorry @EJP, I just try you said, but no affected. So I confirm that

Comment: I am unable to understand you. 'No affected' doesn't mean anything, and it isn't clear what you are 'confirming'.